# Finding minimum hops to a node in a graph - BFS or DFS?

Tags: algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search, depth-first-search, greedy

Is it safe to say that in a problem where you're asked to find the minimum number of hops to reach a particular node in a graph, BFS is better than DFS?

I understand, in a search problem, where the task is to search a node, BFS or DFS being better would depend on the nature of the graph. For example, if your graph is a family tree, and you're looking for someone alive, it would be better to use DFS, since the node is more likely to be deep in the graph. Conversely, if you're looking for someone who passed away many years back, BFS would be ideal.

However, in this case, I feel that, even if DFS were to find the node very quickly, it would still need to backtrack, and find all other paths that reach to the destination, and then compare among them to find the path with the least number of hops. For BFS, on the other hand, the first time you find a node, you can conclude that, this is indeed the path with the least number of hops.

My question is

1. **Is it safe to say, in case of searching a 'key' node, the choice between BFS or DFS
   depends on the nature of the graph, but in finding minimum number of hops to reach a
   destination node, BFS is better ?**
2. **What is the time complexity of finding the minimum number of hops to
   reach a destination node in case of BFS and DFS. For BFS, I think it
   would O(V+E). What is the time complexity in case of DFS ? Would it be exponential, that is V^V, since it's possible for a node to be connected to all other nodes, including itself**

My code using DFS

```
/* Depth First Search */
public int DFSrecursive(Vertex source, Vertex destination)
{
    if(source == destination)
    {
        source.visited = false;
        return 0;
    }


    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE-1;
    for(int i = 0;i<source.neighbors.size();i++)
    {
        Vertex neighbor = source.neighbors.get( i );
        if(neighbor.visited == false)
        {
            neighbor.visited = true;
            min = Math.min( min, DFSrecursive( neighbor, destination )+1 );
        }
    }

    source.visited = false;
    return min;
}
```

My code using BFS

```
/* Breadth First Search */
    public int distBFSHashtable(Vertex source, Vertex destination)
    {
        /* Everything in the queue will be unique, because if, already visited, I don't push into queue.
         * Also, at the time of pushing itself, I made it's visited to be true */
        Queue<Vertex> toprocess = new LinkedList<>();

        toprocess.add( source );
        source.visited = true;

        /* This table gives the distance of each vertex from source */
        Hashtable<Vertex, Integer> distanceTable = new Hashtable<>();
        distanceTable.put( source, 0 );

        while(toprocess.size() > 0 )
        {
            Vertex current = toprocess.poll();

            for(int i = 0;i<current.neighbors.size();i++)
            {
                Vertex neighbor = current.neighbors.get( i );
//                distanceTable.put( neighbor, distanceTable.get( current )+1 );

                if(neighbor.visited == false)
                {
                    neighbor.visited = true;
                    toprocess.add( neighbor );
                    distanceTable.put( neighbor, distanceTable.get( current )+1 );
                }

                if(neighbor == destination)
                    return distanceTable.get( neighbor );
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: DFS is just the wrong tool for this problem. You would have to revisit a lot of nodes. BFS is basically a special form of Dijkstra's algorithm for unweighted graphs.

Comment: @NicoSchertler, I understand BFS is better here. But what is the time complexity of DFS here, is my question.

Comment: The complexity of DFS is always O(|V|+|E|), since no already-visited vertex is visited a second time -- but all it promises is to find *some* path to each reachable vertex, which in general will *not* be the shortest path.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, which is why, we try and find every single path, and compare among them to find the minimum hops. So, the question comes down to, "what is the the time complexity of finding all paths in a graph". Is that O(V^V), that is, exponential, is what I'm trying to ask. What do you feel?

Comment: DFS *does not find every single path*.  Your question asks about DFS, and your `DFSrecursive()` function implements DFS, and DFS takes O(|V|+|E|) time and finds *one* path to each reachable vertex, which may or may not be the shortest.  If you want to know something about finding every single path, as your latest comment suggests, don't ask about DFS.  The number of simple paths in a complete n-vertex graph is n! (n factorial), which is O(n^n), though the latter is not a tight bound.

Comment: @j_random_hacker the DFSrecursive() method above, is indeed computing the number of hops for all paths, and computing the min among all paths - there is a for loop, and also I'm setting a visited node to unvisited for backtracking, when I exit a path. According to me, the time complexity of DFSrecursive() is n! as per your explanation. What do you say?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `source.visited = false;` line.  So the algorithm you have coded there is not what is commonly called "DFS", and yes, it will find a minimum-length path in in O(|V|!) time, which is within O(|V|^|V|) time.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, you're right, I shouldn't be calling it DFS. Firstly, there's  no search here. Thanks for the time complexity analysis.